# What is the best way to refactor presentation code out of my domain objects in an ASP.NET MVC solution?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, refactoring, domain-object

I have just taken over an ASP.NET MVC project and some refactoring is required, but I wanted to get some thoughts / advice for best practices.

The site has an SQL Server backend and here is a review of the projects inside the solution:

- **DomainObjects** (one class per database table)
- **DomainORM** (mapping code from objects to DB)
- **Models** (business logic)
- **MVC** (regular ASP.NET MVC web setup)
  ---- Controllers
  ---- ViewModels
  ---- Views
  ---- Scripts

The first "issue" I see is that while the Domain objects classes are pretty much [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) with some extra "get" properties around calculated fields, there is some presentation code in the Domain Objects. For example, inside the DomainObjects project, there is a **Person** object and I see this property on that class:

```
 public class Person
 {

    public virtual string NameIdHTML
    {
        get
        {
           return "<a href='/People/Detail/" + Id + "'>" + Name + "</a> (" + Id + ")";
        }
    }
 }
```

so obviously having HTML-generated content inside the domain object seems wrong.

**Refactor Approaches**:

1. My first instinct was to move this to the ViewModel class inside the MVC project, but I see that there are a lot of views that hit this code so I don't want to duplicate code in each view model.
2. The second idea was to create PersonHTML class that was either:

   2a. A wrapper that took in a Person in the constructor or

   2b. A class that inherited from Person and then has all of these HTML rendering methods.

   The view Model would convert any Person object to a PersonHTML object and use that for all rendering code.

I just wanted to see:

1. If there is a best practice here as it seems like this is a common problem / pattern that comes up
2. How bad is this current state considered because besides feeling wrong, it is not really causing any major problems understanding the code or creating any bad dependencies. Any arguments to help describe why leaving code in this state is bad from a real practical sense (vs. a theoretical separation of concerns argument) would be helpful as well as there is debate in the team whether it's worth it to change.

Comment: You could create a partial class for that entity in your MVC project, and add the properties you need (such as NameWithIdHTML).

Comment: Leora, the main thing is that NameWithIdHtml is a UI concern and shouldn't feature in your Domain Objects, although from your description you have anemic domain Objects. I think its probably better cleaning it up now which will hopefully lead the way. Maybe create a helper in your presentation layer to produce your html passing in your person attributes, then you could move your business logic into your clean domain objects.

Comment: I'm quite tempted to use this question for a workshop on software architecture! It's a good question and you've given good detail for it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like TBD's comment. It's wrong because you are mixing domain concerns with UI concerns. This causes a coupling that you could avoid.

As for your suggested solutions, I don't really like any of them.

1. Introducing a view model. Yes, we should use view models, but we
   don't want to pollute them with HTML code. So an example of using a
   view would be if you've got a parent object, person type, and you
   want to show the person type on the screen. You would fill the view
   model with the person type name and not a full person type object
   because you only need the person type name on the screen. Or if
   your domain model had first and last name separate, but your view
   calls for FullName, you would populate the view model's FullName and
   return that to the view.
2. PersonHtml class. I'm not even sure what that would do. Views are what represent the HTML in an ASP.NET MVC application. You've got two options here:

   a. You could create a display template for you model. Here's a link to a Stack Overflow question to display templates, *[How to make display template in MVC 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357770/how-to-make-display-template-in-mvc-4-project)*

   b. You could also write a HtmlHelper method that would generate the correct HTML for you. Something like @Html.DisplayNameLink(...) Those would be your best options. Here's a link for understanding HtmlHelpers https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/f/11f721aa-d749-4ed7-bb89-a681b68894e6/ASPNET_MVC_Tutorial_9_CS.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I've wrestled with this myself. When I had code in views that were more logic based than HTML, I created an enhanced version of the HtmlBuilder. I extended certain domain objects to automatically print out this helper, with it's contents based off of domain functions, that could then just be printed onto a view. However, the code becomes very cluttered and unreadable (especially when your trying to figure out where it came from); for these reasons, I suggest removing as much presentation/view logic from the domain as possible.

However, after that I decided to take another look at Display and Editor Templates. And I've come to appreciate them more, especially when combined with T4MVC, FluentValidation, and custom Metadata Providers, among other things. I've found using HtmlHelpers and extending the metadata or routing table to much more cleaner way of doing things, but you also start playing with systems that are less documented. However, this case is relatively simple.

So, first off, I would ensure you have a route defined for that entity, which is looks like you would with the default MVC route, so you can simply do this in a view:

```
//somewhere in the view, set the values to the desired value for the person you have
@{
    var id = 10; //random id
    var name = "random name";
}
//later:
<a href="@Url.Action("People", "Detail", new { id = id })"> @name  ( @id )</a>
```

Or, with [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC):

```
<a href="@Url.Action(MVC.People.Detail(id))"> @name ( @id )</a>
```

This means, with regards to the views/viewmodels, the only dependency these have is the `id` and `name` of the `Person`, which I would presume your existing view models ought to have (removing that ugly `var id = x` from above):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("People", "Detail", new { id = Model.PersonId } )"> 
    @Model.Name ( @Model.PersonId )
</a>
```

Or, with T4MVC:

```
<a href="@Url.Action( MVC.People.Detail( Model.PersonId ) )"> 
    @Model.Name ( @Model.PersonId )
</a>
```

Now, as you said, several views consume this code, so you would need to change the views to conform to the above. There are other ways do it, but every suggestion I have would require changing the views, and I believe this is the cleanest way. This also has a feature of using the route table, meaning that if the routing system is updated, then the updated url would print out here without worries, as opposed to hard coding it in the domain object as a url (that is dependent on the route system to have been set up in a specific manner for that url to work).

One of the my other suggestions would be to build a Html Helper, called `Html.LinkFor( c => model )` or something like that, but, unless if you want it to dynamically determine the controller/action based off the type, that is kind of unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

> How bad is this current state considered because besides feeling wrong, it not really causing any major problems understanding the code or creating any bad dependencies.

The current state is *very* bad, not only because UI code is included in domain code. That would be already *pretty* bad, but this is worse. The `NameIdHTML` property returns a *hardcoded link* to the person's UI page. Even in UI code you should not hardcode these kind of links. That is what `LinkExtensions.ActionLink` and `UrlHelper.Action` are for.

If you change your controller or your route, the link will change. `LinkExtensions` and `UrlHelper` are aware of this and you don't need any further changes. When you use a hardcoded link, you need to find *all* places in your code where such a link is hardcoded (and you need to be aware that those places exist). To make matters even worse, the code you need to change is in the business logic which is *in the opposite direction* of the chain of dependencies. This is a maintenance nightmare and a major source of errors. You need to change this.

> If there is a best practice here as it seems like this is a common problem / pattern that comes up.

Yes, there is a best practice and that is using the mentioned `LinkExtensions.ActionLink` and `UrlHelper.Action` methods whenever you need a link to a page returned by a controller action. The bad news is that this means changes at multiple spots in your solution. The good news is that it's easy to find those spots: just remove the `NameIdHTML` property and the errors will pop up. Unless you are accessing the property by reflection. You will need to do a more careful code search in this case.

You will need to replace `NameIdHTML` by code that uses `LinkExtensions.ActionLink` or `UrlHelper.Action` to create the link. I assume that `NameIdHTML` returns HTML code that should be used whenever this person is to be shown on an HTML page. I also assume that this is a common pattern in your code. If my assumption is true, you can create a helper class that converts business objects to their HTML representations. You can add extension methods to that class that will provide the HTML representation of your objects. To make my point clear I assume (hypothetically), that you have a `Department` class that also has `Name` and `Id` and that has a similar HTML representation. You can then overload your conversion method:

```
public static class BusinessToHtmlHelper {
    public static MvcHtmlString FromBusinessObject( this HtmlHelper html, Person person) {
        string personLink = html.ActionLink(person.Name, "Detail", "People",
            new { id = person.Id }, null).ToHtmlString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(personLink + " (" + person.Id + ")");
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString FromBusinessObject( this HtmlHelper html,
        Department department) {

        string departmentLink = html.ActionLink(department.Name, "Detail", "Departments",
            new { id = department.Id }, null).ToHtmlString();
        return new MvcHtmlString(departmentLink + " (" + department.Id + ")");
    }
}
```

In your views you need to replace `NameIdHTML` by a call to this helper method. For example this code...

```
@person.NameIdHTML
```

...would need to be replaced by this:

```
@Html.FromBusinessObject(person)
```

That would also keep your views clean and if you decide to change the visual representation of `Person` you can easily change `BusinessToHtmlHelper.FromBusinessObject` without changing any views. Also, changes to your route or controllers will be automatically reflected by the generated links. And the UI logic remains with the UI code, while business code stays clean.

If you want to keep your code completely free from HTML, you can create a display template for your person. The advantage is that all your HTML is with the views, with the disadvantage of needing a display template for each type of HTML link you want to create. For `Person` the display template would look something like this:

```
@model Person

@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "Detail", "People", new { id = Model.Id }, null) ( @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Id) )
```

You would have to replace your references to `person.NameIdHTML` by this code (assuming your model contains a `Person` property of type `Person`):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person)
```

You can also add display templates later. You can create `BusinessToHtmlHelper` first and as a second refactoring step in the future, you change the helper class after introducing display templates (like the one above):

```
public static class BusinessToHtmlHelper {
    public static MvcHtmlString FromBusinessObject<T>( this HtmlHelper<T> html, Person person) {
        return html.DisplayFor( m => person );
    }
    //...
}
```

If you were careful only to use links created by `BusinessToHtmlHelper`, there will be no further changes required to your views.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to provide a perfect answer to this issue. Although a total separation of layers is desirable, it often causes a lot useless engineering problems.

Although everyone is ok with the fact that the business layer must not know to much about the presentation/UI layer, I think it's acceptable for it to know these layers do exist, of course without too many details.

Once you have declared that, then you can use a very underused interface: [IFormattable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx). This is the interface that [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) uses.

So, for example, you could first define your Person class like this:

```
public class Person : IFormattable
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // reroute standard method to IFormattable one
        return ToString(null, null);
    }

    public virtual string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (format == null)
            return Name;

        if (format == "I")
            return Id;

        // note WebUtility is now defined in System.Net so you don't need a reference on "web" oriented assemblies
        if (format == "A")
            return string.Format(formatProvider, "<a href='/People/Detail/{0}'>{1}</a>", WebUtility.UrlEncode(Id), WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Name));

        // implement other smart formats

        return Name;
    }
}
```

This is not perfect, but at least, you'll be able to avoid defining hundreds of specified properties and keep the presentation details in a ToString method that was meant speficially for presentation details.

From calling code, you would use it like this:

```
string.Format("{0:A}", myPerson);
```

or use MVC's [HtmlHelper.FormatValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.formatvalue.aspx). There are a *lot* of classes in .NET that support IFormattable (like StringBuilder for example).

You can refine the system, and do this instead:

```
    public virtual string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        ...
        if (format.StartsWith("A"))
        {
            string url = format.Substring(1);
            return string.Format(formatProvider, "<a href='{0}{1}'>{2}</a>", url, WebUtility.UrlEncode(Id), WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Name));
        }
        ...
        return Name;
    }
```

You would use it like this:

```
string.Format("{0:A/People/Detail/}", person)
```

So you don't hardcode the url in the business layer. With the web as a presentation layer, you'll usually have to pass a CSS class name in the format to avoid hardcoding style in the business layer. In fact, you can come up with quite sophisticated formats. After all, this is what's done with objects such as [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) if you think about it.

You can even go further and use some ambiant/static property that tells you if you're running in a web context so it works automatically, like this:

```
public class Address : IFormattable
{
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    ....

    public virtual string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179716/how-determine-if-application-is-web-application
        if ((format == null && InWebContext) || format == "H")
            return string.Join("<br/>", Recipient, Line1, Line2, ZipCode + " " + City, Country);

        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Recipient, Line1, Line2, ZipCode + " " + City, Country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you will want to refactor your code to use view models. The view models can have utility methods for simple string formatting e.g.

```
public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}"
```

But strictly NO HTML! (Being a good citizen :D)

You can then create various Editor/Display templates in the following directories:

```
Views/Shared/EditorTemplates
Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates
```

Name the templates after the model object type, e.g.

```
AddressViewModel.cshtml
```

You can then use the following to render display/editor templates:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Address)
```

If the property type is AddressViewModel, then the AddressViewModel.cshtml from the EditorTemplates, or DisplayTemplates directory will be used.

You can further control the rendering by passing in options to the template like so:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Address, new { show_property_name = false, ... })
```

You can access these values in the template cshtml file like so:

```
@ {
    var showPropertyName = ViewData.ContainsKey("show-property-name") ? (bool)ViewData["show-property-name] : true;
    ...
}

@if(showPropertyName)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertyName)
}
```

This allows for a lot of flexibility, but also the ability to override the template that is used by applying the UIHint attribute to the property like so:

```
[UIHint("PostalAddress")]
public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
```

The DisplayFor/EditorFor methods will now look for the 'PostalAddress.cshtml' template file, which is just another template file like AddressViewModel.cshtml.

I always break down UI into templates like this for projects that i work on, as you can package them via nuget and use them in other projects.

Also, you could also add them to a new class library project, and have them compiled into a dll, which you can just reference in you MVC projects. I have used RazorFileGenerator to do this previously (http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html), but now prefer using nuget packages, as it allows for versioning of the views.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to have a plan before you change it. Yes, projects that you mentioned don't sound correct, but that does not mean the new plan is better.

First, existing projects (this will help you see what to avoid):

DomainObjects containing database tables? that sounds like DAL. I'm assuming that those objects are actually stored in the DB (e.g. if they are entity framework classes) and not mapped from them (e.g. using entity framework and then mapping results back to thse objects), otherwise you have too many mappings (1 from EF to data objects, and 2 from data objects to Models). I've seen that done, very typical mistake in layering. So if you have that, don't repeat that. Also, don't name projects containing data row objects as DomainObjects. Domain means Model.

DomainORM - Ok, but I'd combine it with the data row objects. Makes no sense to keep the mapping project separate, if it's tightly coupled with data objects anyway. It's like pretending you can replace one without the other.

Models - good name, it could mention Domain too, that way nobody would name other projects with this very important word.

NameIdHTML property - bad idea on business objects. But that's a minor refactoring - move that into a method that leaves somewhere else, not inside your business logic.

Business objects looking like DTOs - also bad idea. Then what's the point of the business logic? my own article on this: [How to Design Business Objects](http://www.tutisani.com/software-architecture/how-to-design-business-objects.html)

Now, what you need to target (if you are ready to refactor):

Business logic hosting project should be platform independent - no mention of HTML, or HTTP, or anything related to a concrete platform.

DAL - should reference business logic (not other way around), and should be responsible for mapping as well as holding the data objects.

MVC - keep thin controllers by moving logic out to business logic (where the logic is really a business logic), or into so called Service layer (a.k.a. Application logic layer - optional and exists if necessary to put application specific code out of controllers).

My own article on layering: [Layering Software Architecture](http://www.tutisani.com/software-architecture/layering-software-architecture.html)

Real reasons to do so:

Reusable business logic on potentially several platforms (today you are web only, tomorrow you can be web and services, or desktop too). All different platforms should be using same business logic ideally, if they belong to the same bounded context.

Manageable complexity long run, which is the well known factor for choosing something like DDD (domain driven) vs data-driven design. It comes with learning curve, so you invest into it initially. Long-run, you keep your maintainability low, like receiving premiums perpetually. Beware of your opponents, they will argue it's completely different from what they've been doing, and it will seem complex to them (due to learning curve and thinking iteratively to maintain the good design long run).

Answer (score 0):

First consider your goal and Kent Beck's points about Economics of Software Development. Probably, the goal of your software is to deliver value and you should spend your time on doing something valuable.

Second, wear your Software Architect's hat, and *make some kind of calculation. This is how you back up the choice to spend resources on this or to spend on something else*.

Leaving code in that state would be bad, if within the next 2 years it were going to:

- increase the number of unhappy customers
- reduce your company's revenue
- increase the number of software failure/bugs/crashes
- increase cost of maintenance or change of your code
- surprise developers, causing them to waste hours of time in a misunderstanding
- increase the cost of onboarding new developers

If these things are unlikely to happen as a result of the code then **don't waste your team's life on straightening pencils**. If you can't identify a real negative cost-consequence of the code, then the code is probably okay and it's your theory that should change.

My guess would be “The cost of changing this code is probably higher than the cost of problems it causes.” But you are better placed to guess actual cost of problems. In your example the cost of change might be quite low. Add this to your option 2 refactor list:

————————————————————————————————————

2c. Use extensions methods in the MVC app to add presentation know-how to domain objects with minimal code.

```
public static class PersonViewExtensions
{
    const string NameAndOnePhoneFormat="{0} ({1})";
    public static string NameAndOnePhone(this Person person)
    {
        var phone = person.MobilePhone ?? person.HomePhone ?? person.WorkPhone;
        return string.Format(NameAndOnePhoneFormat, person.Name, phone);
    }
}
```

Where you have embedded HTML, the code in @Sefe's answer — using **extension methods on the `HtmlHelper` class** – is pretty much what I would do. Doing that is great feature of Asp.NetMVC

———————————————————————————————————————

But this approach should be the learned habit of the whole team. *Don't ask your boss for a budget for refactoring. Ask your boss for a budget for learning*: books, time to do coding katas, budget for taking the team to developer meetups.

*Do not, whatever you do, do the amateur-software-architecture-thing* of thinking, “this code doesn't conform to X, therefore we must spend time and money changing it even though we can show no concrete value for that expense.”

Ultimately, your goal is to add value. Spending money on learning will add value; spending money on delivering new features or removing bugs may add value ; spending money on rewriting working code only adds value if you are genuinely removing defects.

Comment: Fixing the described issue will add value. I've seen (and maintained and refactored) my share of messy systems and I know the "it's not broken so let's not spend money on fixing it" argument. This does not consider that systems are running and maintained for years. And what nobody seems to see is the amount if time and money spent over this time in fixing avoidable bugs, overly complex maintenance and the slow learning curves if new developers. In my experience, these kind of changes always are worth their money in the course of the product lifecycle.

Comment: You might be right, but my point about amateur-software-architecting is that without some real analysis of the facts, *not just of the code but of the business*, then *we do not know*. There may be really exciting and valuable features waiting to be delivered that are worth 100x the cost of not fixing this. Or the system may get binned next year. If you are right, then the team should be able to verbalise at least some examples of how the code is hurting them. Devs sometimes have tunnel vision: we see problems in the code but don't see it in the context of the business that the code serves.

Comment: I've seen systems so messy that yor 100x valuable exciting feature would only be implementable with prohibitive costs. I've seen teams struggeling with timelines on new features because they were held up by old avoidable bugs. Implementing new features and fixing old code often are not contradicting each other, one is often necessary to enable the other. Plus, if you don't start fixing at least the really bad stuff, bad habits persist. Systems like that are almost always a symptom of bad development habits and if you don't fix at least the worst problems these habits won't change.

Comment: And secondly :-) If the code is hurting, then I would *still* say better to ask for a budget for learning than to ask for a budget for refactoring! Investing in the team is more valuable to the business and to the team that investing in refactoring.
Look, if the team didn't need the learning, they wouldn't even be asking this question, they'd just be refactoring as they go along already. Yes?

Comment: It depends on how bad your system ist. I'm leaning towards the pragmatic in these cases, but the "rather leave it alone" approach is a wee bit _too_ pragmatic for my taste. On a system with _some_ issues I'll get along without refactoring. On an _unmaintainable_ system I won't. The given example by the OP is really, really bad. And even on a large system it is fixed in half a day. You only need an issue in the production system once and you already have spent a lot more. Even when it pops up in a test system, in the course of the product lifecycle you are almost guaranteed higher cost.